# InstallShield: How to invoke Custom Action only when feature selected

Tags: installshield, custom-action

I have InstallShield Basic MSI Project with two features: A and B.

User can run generated setup.exe, follow Installation Wizard, select Custom Installation Type, select features A or (and) B to install and click Install. And only selected features should be installed.

My problem is - feature A has its own setup.exe (in fact this is Standalone installer with own customized installation Wizard) and I want to launch this setup.exe if user selected this feature and clicked Install. The main installation dialog should be suspended until I finish with installation dialog of feature A. 
Installing of feature B (Feature B doesn't have any installation dialogs and just copies several dlls to destination folder and registers some of them) should start only when I finish with feature A.

How can I get this behavior using InstallShield Custom Actions? What Exec Sequence and Exec Condition should I set for this Custom ACtion?

Answer (score 2):

See [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can write statements like &FEATURENAME=3.  Personally I tend to use components instead of features.  It depends on what the custom action does and what the dependency relationship is.

That said, your design is not really valid.  Windows Installer has mutexes that prevent what you are trying to do.  You should really look at Setup and Feature Prerequisites or Suite Installers to create a chained installer solution.

Comment: Christopher, thank you for your answer. I tried Feature Prerequisites before writing my first question in this topic (I set my feature's  setup.exe as an Application to Run in a Prerequisite properties and set Prerequisite's Conditional Installation settings). But this approach causes error during installation. I'll try to describe it:  I select my feature A and click install -> wizard of feature A appears -> installation process of feature A begins -> An error occured during the move data process -113.

Comment: And one important thing I want to add to my previous message. I want to have only setup.exe file for my product installation (Single Executable Installation image type). So, Feature's executable that is launched when I select this feature to install should be included into setup.exe and 'Extract from Setup.exe' is set as its prerequisite location. I suppose this fact can cause error I described above.

Comment: Move Data Process -113 sounds like an old InstallShield InstallScript error message.  I haven't heard it in years so I'm not sure how to trouble shoot.  Your parent installer sounds like it's correctly authored and calling the child installer which is then failing.  Look for your problem there.   Yes, InstallShield can compress all of your prereqs into a single setup.exe.

Comment: A quick google tells me to try running your setup.exe as administrator and see if that makes the 113 error go away.   InstallShield has some settings that control the elevation story and you'll have to adjust them.

Comment: I tried it, still no success. I suppose another thing can cause this error. Windows installers can extract some data to C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp. What's going on in my situation: 1)I launch main setup.exe 2) C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\{D8725459-0BF7-47A7-818A-13A9F8FFB837} created 3) I select feature and click install 4) I see that other folder C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\{065152E6-58B9-447C-9517-21B28CC6D6C4} is created and setup.exe (together with dlls that used by it) of my feature is placed there.

Comment: This is expected behavior of Windows Installers as I know. But suddenly 065152E6-58B9-447C-9517-21B28CC6D6C4 folder's content is cleaned and as a result "error occured during the move data process -113" occurs... So, I cannot understand why content of this folder is cleaned at this moment. I suppose temp folders should be cleaned only when I finish installation!